# What does さちゅえい mean?

Tags: meaning, register, phonology, diminutives

I can't find this in any dictionary, but it seems to mean something like picture. Is that right?

I don't have an example sentence, because that word was the whole sentence.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Sentence or it didn't exist. (no I didn't downvote this - I've never downvoted even once in JLU)

Comment: Yes, you have a nasty habit of never putting example sentences.

Comment: Looking on Google, I don't think example _sentences_ will help... example _pages_, maybe. It has less than 10,000 hits, so it might be very difficult to give an answer...

Comment: "That word was the whole sentence"?  Was it a blog post title, or a picture caption, or something?  If that's the case, a link would help.  It's often difficult to translate without context.

Comment: @sawa: You added a [[tag:diminutive]] tag, but how is this question related to [diminutives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive)?  If I understand the technical terms correctly, さちゅえい is a (mock) baby-talk, not a diminutive.  The same applies to some of the other questions to which you added the [diminutive] tag recently.

Comment: さちゅえい is contrasted to さつえい, and can be considered the diminutive form of the latter. If you consider the phoneme "ch" which replaces "ts", or more precisely the phonological feature that is added to make the sound change, I think that can be considered a diminutive morpheme.

Comment: @sawa: Baby-talks can be often made by sound changes, so that does not explain that さちゅえい is a diminutive.  My understanding is that さつえい and さちゅえい mean the same things.  If you want to keep your view in tags, I do not care unless it is my question, but I am afraid that you are simply conflating baby-talks and diminutives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it comes from 撮影【さつえい】 where つ becomes ちゅ for some reason (slang?). A bit like おやちゅみなさい.

Seems to me that さちゅえい refers to [撮影会](http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E6%92%AE%E5%BD%B1%E4%BC%9A&oldid=38536575) events. There are many types of 撮影会 but the main ones are for amateur photographers to meet, to take a picture with a character or model, to create publicity with an open photoshoot, or to recruit new models. They are discussed in more detail on Wikipedia.

Comment: I learned that it's pronounced that way by kids, because they can't pronounce certain letters.

Comment: @language you're correct on that one, but just to note that sometimes such "kiddish" spelling is made to entice newbies.

Comment: Some (if not many) Chinese pronounce it that way.  I had a few Chinese friends, and they could not pronounce `つ` very well, and it always came out as `ちゅ`.